# Jmeter Magento Error

Tags: jmeter, magento-2.0

I'm trying to run JMeter for performance testing on a Magento 2 website. So, far I've been able to integrate the `benchmark.jmx` file provided by Magento into JMeter. But when I try to run it, it starts and ends immediately. This is the error I get

```
2016/09/01 09:43:43 WARN  - jmeter.testbeans.BeanInfoSupport: Localized strings not available for bean class kg.apc.jmeter.config.redis.RedisDataSet java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name kg.apc.jmeter.config.redis.RedisDataSetResources, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.BeanInfoSupport.<init>(BeanInfoSupport.java:126)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.config.redis.RedisDataSetBeanInfo.<init>(RedisDataSetBeanInfo.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(InstanceFinder.java:96)
    at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(InstanceFinder.java:66)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Introspector.java:438)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:388)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI.<init>(TestBeanGUI.java:168)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.initializeMenus(MenuFactory.java:488)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.<clinit>(MenuFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

2016/09/01 09:43:44 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file /home/yassar/Downloads/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/proxyserver.jks 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_qos] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_most_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_least_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_exactly_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_client_types] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_blocking_client] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_async_client] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type_text] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type_file] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_qos] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_most_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_least_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_exactly_once] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_client_types] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_blocking_client] 
2016/09/01 09:43:45 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_async_client] 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.DistributionGraphVisualizer 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2016/09/01 09:43:46 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SplineVisualizer 
2016/09/01 10:25:41 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/09/01 10:25:41 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/09/01 10:25:41 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/09/01 10:25:41 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/09/01 10:25:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: No enabled thread groups found 
2016/09/01 10:25:42 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/09/01 10:25:42 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/home/yassar/Downloads/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin' 
2016/09/01 10:25:42 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /home/yassar/Downloads/benchmark.jmx 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/yassar/Downloads' 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.9 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: /home/yassar/Downloads/benchmark.jmx 
2016/09/01 10:25:50 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/yassar/Downloads/benchmark.jmx', cannot determine class for element: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:  is-copy-enabled is-u2f-enabled
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:533)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.loadTree(SaveService.java:503)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:62)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException:  is-copy-enabled is-u2f-enabled
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper$1.realClass(SaveService.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:31)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:133)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.readTree(SaveService.java:524)
    ... 21 more

2016/09/01 10:26:12 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /home/yassar/Projects/m205/setup/performance-toolkit/benchmark.jmx 
2016/09/01 10:26:12 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/yassar/Projects/m205/setup/performance-toolkit' 
2016/09/01 10:26:12 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: /home/yassar/Projects/m205/setup/performance-toolkit/benchmark.jmx 
2016/09/01 10:26:12 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2016/09/01 10:26:13 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/yassar/Projects/m205/setup/performance-toolkit' 
2016/09/01 10:27:08 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/yassar/Projects/m205/setup/performance-toolkit' 
2016/09/01 10:27:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/09/01 10:27:11 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/09/01 10:27:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting setUp thread groups 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting setUp ThreadGroup: 1 : setUp Thread Group 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group setUp Thread Group. 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Test will stop on error 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Waiting for all setup thread groups to exit 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``Boolean stopTestOnError (String error) {     log.error(error);     System.out.pr . . . '' : Method Invocation path.substring 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``Boolean stopTestOnError (String error) {     log.error(error);     System.out.pr . . . '' : Method Invocation path.substring 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Test detected by thread: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: setUp Thread Group 1-1 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All Setup Threads have ended 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: No enabled thread groups found 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting tearDown thread groups 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/09/01 10:27:12 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing some plug-ins that are used along with this JMX. You need to copy these plug-ins in under JMeter /lib/ext folder and it should work.

Check what plug-ins are being used by the benchmark.jmx

Answer (score 1):

Success Finally...

I have been able to launch it. Actually the issue was mostly with urls. I dont know why but 'host' and 'admin_path' variables work in funny ways with Magento. But i find a walk around by manually going through the 'html requests' and added the variable required. Now it is running

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the Redis Data Set plugin also.
Please take a look at: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/